Word Boundary in awk
I am trying to extract the lines that contains the word "at" and wrote this
        awk '
            BEGIN { IGNORECASE = 1 }
            /(failed|caused by|errorcode|error code)/ { 
                    if ($0 ~ /exception/ && $0 ~ /(failed|caused by|errorcode|error code)/) {
                    f=1 
                    }
            }
  
            f { 
                    print NR ": ", $0
            }

            f && /at/ { 
                    next 
            }
  
            f && !/at/ { 
                    f=0 
            }
        ' "$log_file"

this code works but it also captures the words like "attachement" "attraction" but what I want is to exactly match the word "at". so I also tried to set word boundary like this
awk '
            BEGIN { IGNORECASE = 1 }
            /(failed|caused by|errorcode|error code)/ { 
                    if ($0 ~ /exception/ && $0 ~ /(failed|caused by|errorcode|error code)/) {
                    f=1 
                    }
            }
  
            f { 
                    print NR ": ", $0
            }

            f && /\bat\b/ { 
                    next 
            }
  
            f && !/\bat\b/ { 
                    f=0 
            }
        ' "$log_file"

but it prints nothing. then i tried this
awk '
            BEGIN { IGNORECASE = 1 }
            /(failed|caused by|errorcode|error code)/ { 
                    if ($0 ~ /exception/ && $0 ~ /(failed|caused by|errorcode|error code)/) {
                    f=1 
                    }
            }
  
            f { 
                    print NR ": ", $0
            }

            f && /\Bat\B/ { 
                    next 
            }
  
            f && !/\Bat\B/ { 
                    f=0 
            }
        ' "$log_file"

it only prints few of the lines with the word "at". also tried this
awk '
            BEGIN { IGNORECASE = 1 }
            /(failed|caused by|errorcode|error code)/ { 
                    if ($0 ~ /exception/ && $0 ~ /(failed|caused by|errorcode|error code)/) {
                    f=1 
                    }
            }
  
            f { 
                    print NR ": ", $0
            }

            f && /\<at\>/ { 
                    next 
            }
  
            f && !/\<at\>/ { 
                    f=0 
            }
        ' "$log_file"

but no use.
can anyone help? Thanks in advance. and also please explain the difference between \b and \B in awk.

Why don't you just match / at /?

@oguzismail : This would fail to match at at the start or end of  a sentence, or in front of a comma for instance. I think that's why the OP explicitly talked about word boundary.

I don't know the variations possible in your input data, but you could prefilter lines with "interesting" words, using grep -Ew 'at|exception|failed|....' "$logfile", and then postprocess the result with your original awk program.

Might have lines like  at: or  at-, or /^at:/ or / at$/.

what about gnu grep  , grep -w at ...

Overkill. What you are basically doing:
awk ' BEGIN { IGNORECASE = 1 }
      /(failed|caused by|errorcode|error code)/ {           # tested here
        if ($0 ~ /exception/ && 
            $0 ~ /(failed|caused by|error *code)/) # why again here?
        { f=1 }                                             # why a flag?
      }
      f { print NR ": ", $0 } # why a block? Do this instead of setting f
      f && /\<at\>/ { next }  # why check at? 
      f && !/\<at\>/ { f=0 }  # most "caused by" lines trigger this...
 ' $file

If all you want is to show lines with both /exception/ & /(failed|caused by|errorcode|error code)/, then just do that. Your extra lines are just causing problems.
You are going to a lot of extra trouble to set f as a flag, but then using overly simple tsts in your fall-through logic that allow it to be un-set on the same record that set it. Your /\<at\>/ isn't even being checked, because f is usually immediately false again.
All you need:
awk ' BEGIN { IGNORECASE = 1 }
      /exception/ && /failed|caused by|error ?code/ { print NR ": ", $0 }
  ' $file

If you want to see the "at" lines you need to say so, because your logic seems to be attempting to exclude them.
I suspect an X/Y Problem here.
If this isn't the solution you need, please clarify the question with actual, relevant info.


explain the difference between \b and \B in awk.

Regarding GNU AWK according to User's Guide

\B Matches the empty string that occurs between two word-constituent
characters.

this is inverse of word boundary, which is \y in GNU AWK, let file.txt content be
a
ab
abc

then
awk '/ab\B/{print "B",$0}/ab\y/{print "y",$0}' file.txt

gives output
y ab
B abc

In GNU AWK \b denotes BACKSPACE character (ASCII number 0x08).
(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)
